# How to disable the "Expect: 100 continue" header in HttpWebRequest for a single request?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

`HttpWebRequest` automatically appends an `Expect: 100-continue` header for POST requests. Various sources around the internet suggest that this can be disabled as follows:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

However, I'm writing a library and I cannot disable this for the entire appdomain, in case the application relies on this behaviour. Nor can I assume that it will remain set to this value. How can I disable it for a specific request?

Comment: This worked for me at last.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The `HttpWebRequest` class has a property called `ServicePoint` which can be used to change this setting for a specific request. For example:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(...);
req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Comment: great answer.  this saved me from having to upgrade clients to .NET 4.5 in order to set the HttpWebRequest.ContinueTimeout property.

Comment: at runtime it automatically added again

Answer (score 24):

If you also need to set a proxy, make sure to do that first. Otherwise **Expect100Continue** will be reverted to **true** again. So:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(_url);
webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(_proxyHost, _proxyPort);
webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Comment: Setting proxy re-resolves request's service point (by calling private FindServicePoint method, which leads to ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint method invocation), effectively resetting Expect100Continue property.
As of this writing, RestSharp client, for example, sets proxy and Expect100Continue in incorrect order (see method ConfigureWebRequest of Http class), which leads to 417 http errors.

Comment: This tip is extremely helpful for those who are using proxies and I was having this problem without any explanation.  I tried it and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be overwritten in the config:

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```