# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse times out even with Timeout set to Int32.MaxValue

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest, .net-4.5, restsharp

I'm getting some sort of timeout while waiting for a (POST) request to complete. I'm trying to set up my request to never time out (some requests take ~5 minutes for the server to reply to.)

I've set the RestSharp client **`Timeout` to `Int32.MaxValue`**, which, based on my reading, is passed directly back to the `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` property.

```
// Somewhere in one-time setup
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 128;
IRestClient client = new RestClient(serverUri);
client.FollowRedirects = false;
client.AddHandler(JSON_CONTENT_TYPE, Converter);
client.Timeout = Int32.MaxValue;

RestRequest request = new RestRequest(resource, RestSharp.Method.POST;
IRestResponse response = ExecuteRequest(client, request);
```

At first, this seemed to work, because some POSTs that were taking 3 or 4 minutes started getting through. Every now and then, though, I'll *still* get a timeout, even though only a relatively short amount of time has passed.

Here's one I caught just recently. The request is expected to take about 4 minutes, but after roughly **1 minute and 45 seconds** an exception is raised.

Details of `response.ErrorException`:

`InnerException {"The operation has timed out"} System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}`

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at RestSharp.Http.GetRawResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
at RestSharp.Http.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
```

I've read around and this seems to be the correct timeout setting to use. Apparently the `HttpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout` (which should be defaulting to 5 minutes anyways) shouldn't be a concern. Everything else (correct disposal of connections, etc.) is handled by RestSharp, which I'm assuming is done correctly and certainly works well for short requests.

Any thoughts on what might be causing these sporadic timeouts before the requested timeout has elapsed?

---

*edit* to clarify, we do thousands of requests to this server without issue. The server isn't doing anything special to block us. We have server logs and it's still busy working away at the request when the client disconnects.

Also note that the timeout occurs sporadically and at different times. I just reproduced it now and got "The operation has timed out" after only **36.8s** this time.

Comment: Some server have Anti-Spoof and will not respond when a bad request is sent.  The request may not get routed to the server if a Firewall(or antivirus)  is blocking.  Also Windows may be blocking if you credential aren't correct.  And then you may not have a route to the server.  If you are using IP address try computer name.

Comment: Do your server use the `100-Continue`? If yes, the [`HttpRequest.ContinueTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.continuetimeout?view=netframework-4.5.2) may apply to your request. You may try to simply [disable that behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063329/213550) for a single request or for whole application.

Comment: @jdweng No, it's a known server we control, and it has no problem handling requests 99% of the time. These timeouts are occasional.